# My Canvas on the Image is not zooming along with the Image View.?

Tags: java, android

I am drawing a canvas on my Custom Image View and applying a zoom in and zoom out animation to my custom Image View.The problem is my canvas is not rescaling alongwith the image view.I want the canvas to be fixed with the my custom Image view and zoom with the custom  Image view itself in android.How can I achieve this??

Would appreciate if answered.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use image in html in webview for example ...

```
String data = "<body>" + "<img src=\"resist1.png\"/></body>";
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.resistorWebview);
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", data,
            "text/html", "utf-8", null);

    // webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/image.html");
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.NORMAL);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```